# Bitrix News: created property doesn't display in the editing of an element

Tags: bitrix

I created a property in the News infoblock settings.
Checkbox "Active" and "Show on the page of editing of element" is set.

But I don't see a field where I can set this property when I add or edit an element.

Please, don't send me to oficial Bitrix support. I don't need their "we'll respond you after 3 days".

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have customized element form. If so - you can add new property to edit form
[by clicking 'cogwheel' in right top corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQ7Iq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need add new property on edit page of Iblock's element

See my screenshots:
[image]

[image]

[image]